# I can't use GET and POST at the same time in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, get

Near the top of my page, I have this:

```
<?php $id = $_GET['id']; ?>
```

Then I have some form check conditionals that read from POST:

```
if (isset($_POST['completeSubmit'])) {
        //code
}
```

And finally, I have an HTML form which looks like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=$id"; ?>" name="complete" method="post">
<input type="submit" id="textButton" name="completeSubmit" value="[mark as complete]">
</form>
```

The page is initially accessed by using GET with an id variable like this:

```
http://website.com/page.php?id=1
```

All subsequent form submissions (which get redirected to the same page) fail. I know you can't send both GET and POST in the same request, but seeing as my form is submitting to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=$id"` using POST shouldn't it work? This is my first time trying this so it is quite possible I've overlooked something trivial.

Comment: This should inherently work -- you might want to investigate other areas for possible bugs..

Comment: Yes, this should work. GET and POST at the same time are indeed possible. You can try checking your form's HTML to see if the action attribute is correct. Dumping both $_GET and $_POST vars. in your target page might also be helpful.

Comment: typically the ID and NAME attributes should be equal...

Comment: @jeanreis sorry for disappointing you, but GET and POST at the same time are quite impossible.

Comment: @jlb not that inherently. Say, it won't work for the GET method forms

Comment: @tandu's answer is best here -- while it's true that you cant both HTTP GET and HTTP POST at the same time, $_GET variables should be accessible from a POST request

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel quite right, I didn't explain myself correctly (jlb's answer is better). HTTP POST with GET parameters allows you to access both of them ($_GET and $_POST).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* use get and post at the same time, but you shouldn't.  If you want to continue to send the ID this is as simple as:

```
<form ...
   <input type="submit" ...
   <input type="hidden" name="id"
      value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: +1 for this solution, just send the initial value of $_GET['id'] along with your post request. It's the cleanest way.

Comment: I tried this too and it didn't seem to work. I'll keep on investigating, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Got it to work, turns out there was a little bug hiding around. I opted for this method as it is cleaner.

Comment: I know it's a really old post, but just in case: WHY one shouldn't use post and get at the same time? Is something particularly wrong about it I should be aware of? Or is it just considered 'messy'? My situation: i'm receiving a POST generated externally (payment transaction result), and can only program where to receive it. So I put a parameter in the URL to add my own data to it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you **can not** use GET and POST *methods* simultaneously.

However you can use a *query string* while sending a form using POST method, which being used to populate $_GET array.

To find a certain error you have to provide more info. At least 2 things:

- how does HTML form look
- what do yo see in the query string after posting the form.

and errr...

- do you use any header redirects in the form processing?