# Attach all fields form a from to ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a HTML form with various different types of fields. Input, select, hidden and textarea. I have tried attaching all the form data to the ajax request but the POST data isn't sending. The reason for getting all form data rather than just naming the individual fields is the user can add more fields if the need to.

```
    function saveProductEdits(f){
    var url = 'func/editProduct.php?func=saveEdits';
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        data:$('#edit_form').serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        beforeSend:function(){
        },
        success:function(e){
            alert(e);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['func'])){
        if($_GET['func'] == 'saveEdits'){
            if(!empty($_POST)){
            }else{
                echo 'Post data not sent';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'unknown function';
        }
print_r($_POST); //shows empty array
    }else{
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="edit_form">
  //various inputs generated at run time
  <input type="button" value="Save Changes" onclick="saveProductEdits(this)" /> //button to submit
</form>
```

I keep getting 'Post data not sent'.

UPDATE:

screen shot of network tab

[image]

Im entirly sure but I presume by that the data isn't sending.

UPDATE FORM

```
<p>
  <label for="product_name">Product Name: </label>
  <input id="product_name" type="text" placeholder="Product Name" class="basic_field" value="Product Name PHP" />
</p>
<label for="main_cat">Main Catagory: </label>
<select id="main_cat">
  php generated options
</select>
<div id="cats_list">
  <p>
    <label for="sub_cat_1">Sub Catagory 1: </label>
      php generated options
    </select>
  </p>
</div>
<br/>
<a onclick="newCatField('2','Hair Pieces','6')">Add another Catagory</a>
<input type="hidden" id="count_cats" value="2" />
<div id="sizes">
  <p>
    <label>Size: </label>
    <input type="text" id="size_1" value="1" /> 
    <label>Quantity: </label>
    <input type="number" id="quant_1" value="100" /> 
  </p>
</div>
<a onclick="newSizeField('1')">Add another Size</a>
<input type="hidden" id="size_count" value="1" />
<p>
  <label for="keywords">Keywords: </label>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Link a catagory: 
  <select onChange="addCatToKeywords(this,'keywords')" class="basic_field">      
    <option>Add...</option>
    php generated options
  </select>
  <textarea id="keywords" class="basic_field">php content</textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="desc">Description: </label>
  <textarea id="desc" style="">php content</textarea>
</p>
```

example of adding fields at runtime:
this does work and adds 1 to the id of each on and to a hidden value that counts the added fields.

```
function newCatField(c,u,m){
    $.ajax({
        url:'func/getCats.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{used:u},
        success:function(e){
            if(count === parseInt(m)){
            }else{
                document.getElementById('cats_list').innerHTML += '<p><label for="sub_cat_'+count+'">Sub Catagory '+count+': </label><select id="sub_cat_'+count+'"><option>Please Select</option>'+e+'</select></p>';
                count++;
                document.getElementById('count_cats').value = parseInt($('#count_cats').val()) + 1;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console to see what the outgoing HTTP request looks like?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Not enough arguments on line url:'func/editProduct.php?func=saveEdits',

Comment: That error doesn't make much sense. Is there other code before that "saveEdits" function?

Comment: theres not now I moved this to the top, still geting the no post data sent message. I get rid of the console error by defining the url in a varable above the ajax request

Comment: so is form selector correct? Look at what is actually sent in network tab of console

Comment: Not entirely sure what the data here means see update fro a screenshot, I presume that means the form data isn't sending as it says text/html

Comment: If you click on that row in the "Network" tab, it'll show you more information on the right. The "Headers" tab on the right will tell you what the outgoing HTTP request looked like.

Comment: How exactly is that "saveEdits" function being called? If you're still getting that syntax error, I guess it's probably *not* being called.

Comment: I added a better picture form the network tab

Comment: form an input type button using onclick="myfunction(this)"

Comment: the function is being called as the ajax is returning message from the php file.

Comment: Can you show us the "//various inputs generated at run time"? Besides, it's normally not advised to use both [POST and GET at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954831/i-cant-use-get-and-post-at-the-same-time-in-php), however that's not the cause of the problem this time. I'd recommend [following this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4406348/938236).

Comment: SEE update for the raw form and a function that adds fields at runtime

Comment: try wrapping your `data: $('#...` inside `{}` brackets: `data: { $('#... }`

Comment: Paul, you need to be sure that all of your form elements have the name attribute on them in order to do the form pasting the way you are trying to add it to ajax.

Comment: @KaiHogan adding the same name attr sends some data but $_POST[some id] doesn't retrive the data in the php document  print_r($_POST[name for all]) only shows the last element in the form

Comment: Above comment - a bit of common sense should have told me to use different name for each field. Post this as an answer, works just how I want

Answer (score 2):

**$.serialize()**

Probably [this](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function is what you're looking for.

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that.