# Sending a lot of fields through a post AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have like 143 form fields (text, textarea and select) that I would like to send through an AJAX post request. Is there a way I can do this quick without manually add every field to the query?

---

Alright so I've set up thing like this:

jquery

```
$("#submitbtn").click(function(){
$.ajax({url: "check_data.php", data: $("#form").serialize(), success: function(result){
   alert(result);
}});
```

});

The form is declared like this:

```
<form class="pure-form" onsubmit="return false;" method="POST" id="form">
```

I tried also without the "return: false"

And the button as follow:

```
<button id="submitbtn" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">INSERT</button>
```

But it does not work, when I press the button I get no js or network activity whatsoever on the console, and nothing happens.

Comment: You can serialize the form data. https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach all fields form a from to ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588272/attach-all-fields-form-a-from-to-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using this:

```html
$(function() {
 $("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
   
  $.ajax({
   url: "check_data.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   success: function(d) {
    alert(d);
   }
  });
 });
});
```