# PHP: trouble with understanding POST and GET at the same time

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a webpage where I ask input from the user and when he clicks the add button, it should insert the input from the user into the database. I always thought that you couldn't use POST and GET at the same time but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749406/post-and-get-at-the-same-time-in-php) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954831/i-cant-use-get-and-post-at-the-same-time-in-php) answers it should be possible. Yet, I can't seem to get their solutions working.

The script inserts something in the db (an id is generated) but the seriesName field remains empty.

The PHP script:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","passwd","database");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$issueSeries = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['addSeries']);

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO series (seriesName) VALUES ('$issueSeries')");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="issueAddInformationLayout">
    <div id="issueAddCredits">
        <form action="addIssue.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr id="lblAddCreator">
                    <td><p>NR</p></td>
                    <td><p>Series</p></td>
                    <td><p>Volume</p></td>
                    <td><p>Title</p></td>
                    <td><p>Publisher</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addNR" size="3%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addSeries" size="25%" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addVolume" size="25%" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addTitle" size="30%" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addPublisher" size="30%" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr id="lblAddCreator">
                    <td><p>Writer</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="txtAddCreator">
                    <td><input type="text" id="addWriter1" size="30%" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addWriter2" size="30%" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addWriter3" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addWriter4" size="30%"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="lblAddCreator">
                    <td><p>Editor</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="txtAddEditor">
                    <td><input type="text" id="addEditor1" size="30%" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addEditor2" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addEditor3" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addEditor4" size="30%"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="lblAddCreator"> 
                    <td><p>Letterer</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="txtAddLetterer">
                    <td><input type="text" id="addLetterer1" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addLetterer2" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addLetterer3" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addLetterer4" size="30%"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="lblAddCreator">
                    <td><p>Colourist</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="txtAddColourist">
                    <td><input type="text" id="addColourist1" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addColourist2" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addColourist3" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addColourist4" size="30%"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="lblAddCreator">
                    <td><p>Cover Artist</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="txtAddCoverArtist">
                    <td><input type="text" id="addCoverArtist1" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addCoverArtist2" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addCoverArtist3" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addCoverArtist4" size="30%"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="lblAddCreator">
                    <td><p>Inker</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="txtAddInker">
                    <td><input type="text" id="addInker1" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addInker2" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addInker3" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addInker4" size="30%"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="lblAddCreator">
                    <td><p>Penciler</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    </tr>
                <tr id="txtAddPenciler">
                    <td><input type="text" id="addPenciler1" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addPenciler2" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addPenciler3" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="addPenciler4" size="30%"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="lblAddCreator">
                    <td><p>Trade Paper Back</p></td>
                    <td><p id="lblAddCover">Cover</p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr id="txtAddTPB">
                    <td><input type="text" id="addTPB" size="30%"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <p id="btnAddCover" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="parse_file.php" method="post"> 
                            <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <id="btnAddIssue"><input type="submit" value="Add">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**There seemed to be some confusion about the HTML so I added the full HTML code. Keep in mind: this is purely for myself and I don't really care about stuff like that tables are outdated :)**

Comment: Your input is outside the form...

Comment: @DamienPirsy There seemed to be some confusion about the HTML so I added the full HTML code

Answer (score 1):

In HTTP, you can't use GET and POST at the same time but you can make a POST request which has a query string as part of the URL.

PHP will populate `$_POST` with the body of the request and `$_GET` with the query string, even if the request was a POST request.

Since the form is `POST`, the data from the inputs will be put into the body and not the query string (so will appear in `$_POST` not `$_GET`).

If the value of `addSeries` was *fixed* then you could use it with `$_GET` like so:

```
 <form id="btnAddIssue" action="addIssue.php?addSeries=someValue" method="post">
```

… but since you are taking user input, use `$_POST` to read the value after you put the input inside the form.

Comment: There seemed to be some confusion about the HTML so I added the full HTML code.

Comment: @TimothyPersoon — Your edit has made the HTML invalid. You cannot have nested forms.

Comment: Did not know that, but I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is outside of your form so it isn't submitted.

```
<form id="btnAddIssue" action="addIssue.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="addSeries" size="25%" />
   <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

You then need to change `$_GET['addSeries']` to `$_POST['addSeries']` since your form is set to POST (or change your form to submit via GET).

Answer (score 0):

Your input is outside the form tag which won't be considered when user submits the form.

```
<form id="btnAddIssue" action="addIssue.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="addSeries" size="25%" />
   <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

And since you are making a post request onto php side it would be $_POST to reference that input's value

Also, sometimes it would be good to make use of $_REQUEST which contains data from both GET and POST so you have proper data from request everytime

```
$issueSeries = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['addSeries']);
```

Comment: **Warning**: `$_REQUEST` also includes data from cookies. I'd generally avoid it in favour of knowing exactly where your data was coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Your text filed is placed outside the form and so no value (of that text filed) will be submitted to the action page.

Change it to

```
<form id="btnAddIssue" action="addIssue.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="addSeries" size="25%" />
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Also use $_POST, or you can even use $_REQUEST (you can use $_REQUEST for both get and post variables)

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about the HTML, I have added the entire HTML code